# Lucene.net search not returning results with aphostrophe's or single Quotes?

Tags: lucene.net

I have a search mechanism in my project where i was using lucene.net for searching, I got accurate results for all sentences which i search except for those which starts with "The", but that i have resolved. But i found another issue that Lucene.net search results not returning values which contains aphostrophe's or single quotes. Do anyone know why is that so? Is it really a bug with lucene.net? Or is there any mechanism to include results with aphostrophe's in it?

For example I have searched for the word **"The Lorem"** and **i got the result like**

**"Lorem"**

**"Highlight animation (join dots) for yellow shape without outline"**

**"angles of 60\120 degrees on a straight line (120 degree angle highlighted)"**

*but the expected result is*

**"Lorem"**

**"Highlight animation (join dots) for yellow shape without outline"**

**"angles of 60\120 degrees on a straight line (120 degree angle highlighted)"**

**"The Lorem's"**

**"The Lorem's"**

Comment: I think its not only with single quotes or aphostrophe's. This problem comes along with all special characters. I think Special characters cannot be searched with Lucene.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the analyzers create tokens from your text

Ex:
Input: [The Lorem's]

WhitespaceAnalyzer --> [The] [Lorem's]

StandardAnalyzer   --> [lorem]

SimpleAnalyzer     --> [the] [lorem] [s]